# How can I glob all nested files with subdirectory exceptions

Tags: shell, glob

I am attempting to use shell globbing to grab all nested matchin folders, except for ones in a particular directory

```
|__foo
|  |__foo.txt
|__bar
|  |__bar.txt
|__baz
|  |__baz.txt
```

can i glob to return

`bar/bar.txt`, `baz/baz.txt`

the folders to include will vary, so i need to explicitly exclude the foo directory.  Is this possible?

**PSEUDO CODE**

something like `[**|!foo]/*.txt`

Comment: IMO you can't have alternations between patterns (no `(foo|bar)`) so filtering is difficult. Why not use globbing in combination with `grep -v` or something similar?

Comment: Little unclear, is it always that directory name and file name are same?

Comment: so im restricted to globbing because i am using this within grunt.  yes the exclude directory will always be the same, and the file names to include will be consistent.  I edited the typo of `text` to `txt` if that was part of the confusion :)

Answer (score 4):

In bash, you can use [extended globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing)

For your example

```
$ find
.
./bar
./bar/bar.txt
./biz
./biz/biz.txt
./foo
./foo/foo.txt

# turn on extended globbing
$ shopt -s extglob

# Match files not in foo
$ ls !(foo)/*
bar/bar.txt  biz/biz.txt

# Match files in neither foo nor bar
$ ls !(foo|bar)/*
biz/biz.txt
```